# Is "there are x numbers of something" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, numbers

Instead of saying:

> There are 5 students in the classroom.

can we say:

> There are 5 number(s) of students in the classroom.

In this case should we use number or numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say either *number* or *numbers* in this context.  "There are five students" is correct.  "There are five *number(s)* of students" is wrong.

If you really want to use the word *number*, you could say "The number of students in the classroom was five", but that is a very artificial, stilted way to say it.

Comment: You could also say: "The students in the classroom are five in number"; however, the original sentence is much more idiomatic and commoner than the alternatives.